# How can I create a full-screen slideshow that fades into a collage?

Tags: slideshow

I want to create a full-screen slideshow to run on a monitor in the window of a realtor. I'd like to be able to have the pictures of a particular property arranged as a collage and each one "pop out" and then fade back into the collage.

Ideally, I'd like to use a web-based app but am up for buying a package if necessary. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a graphical photo screensaver, point it to a specific folder (say of a particular home), and the screensaver will do the rest...

Give [**PhotoJoy**](http://www.photojoy.com/welcome.aspx) a try...have used myself, highly recommend, never had a problem with it (spam, etc).

Desktop Collages: http://www.photojoy.com/gallery/gallery.aspx

Or Screensavers: http://www.photojoy.com/gallery/gallery.aspx?type_id=2&id=11215&cat_id=38&coll_id=471